# Strange behavior - access to domain.in/file/file is being allowed

Tags: php, html

I am observing this strange behavior in my website.

i have the following directory structure on my webserver

```
root
login.php
contact.php
myaccount.php
.
.
```

when i type the address in the url as 
`http://www.domain.in/contact.php`  as expected, i get my contact.php rendered on screen.
But when i try to enter the following address as url..
`http://www.domain.in/contact.php/myaccount.php` here i expect  something  from the below to happen :

```
1)  a 404 page to be displayed
2)  a redirect to contact.php
```

But instead, the page `myaccount.php` gets rendered, offcourse not in a fashion i would like it to be.

I basically thought if i can prevent this using htacess file, but i was not able to figure out any rule that can work for this scenario.

Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my last answer, didnt read the question fully.

Try adding this into the top of `myaccount.php`

```
 <?php
 $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 $query = !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : null;
 $url = !empty($query) ? "http://$host$self?$query" : "http://$host$self";
 $redirect = '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4;url=http://www.domain.in/contact.php">';
 if ($url=="http://www.domain.in/contact.php/myaccount.php") echo $redirect;
 // The Rest of the page here
 ?>
```

Comment: hi Ron, thanks for the quick reply and a great solution.i understand your approach. but the thing is, this kind of behavior is generic across my website.
is this a bug? or is the natural behavior?
so if i have to take your approach, i need to put this code in every other file in my website. 
i was hoping to see if we can have a htaccess approach which can address this issue.
Again, thanks for your help